# subgroups is normal if it is the only subgroups that has order n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

In my last lecture in Abstract Algebra the lecturer used this proposition:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$ subgroup of G. if $H$ is the only
>   subgroup that $\mid H \mid = n$ of G then $H \lhd G$

I cant understand why..

P.S: we proved before that:

For all $g \in G$ then $ gH g^{-1} \cong H $ and   $gH g^{-1} \leq G$

Answer (score 5):

Here automatically $H=gHg^{-1}$ for each $g$. This because $|gHg^{-1}|=n$

Comment: why |gHg^-1|=n?

Comment: you have the bijection $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ from $H$ to $gHg^{-1}$

Comment: I don't belive i miss it: |gHg^-1|=|H| (isomorphic)=n=> two subgroup with n order=>gHg^-1=H... thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to show that under problem's conditions, $gHg^{-1}\leq G$ and $$|g^{-1}Hg|=|H|=n$$

- $gHg^{-1}\neq \emptyset$.
- $(gh_1g^{-1})(gh_2g^{-1})=gh_1h_2g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.
- $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=gh^{-1}g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.